# Error 424 Object required when working with Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets, and I need to work with them.

Start sheet - where the original consumer number is located

sheet 1 - where I need to match the consumer number and get the value on column

Final Sheet - need to use another match and populate column I with the reason.

I am trying to add 4 columns in a dictionary where the key will be the value of 2 columns.
I need to link the consumer number with the Con #.e.g

S. Consumer Number = S.Con #   **///** *P. Consumer number = P. Con#*

119 = 1000000000000297914      **///**     *18  = 2000000000078038566*

Because I will need to use the S. Consumer Number and P. Consumer number to find the match in another sheet use the Status Reason for this consumer in another sheet.

On the Sheet named Final, the Reason needs to be added to a column I if the consumer number matches.

```
Dim dictConsumerNumber As Object, dictCon As Object, row, reason, mreason As Range
                Set wsStart = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Start")
                Set wsFinal = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final")
                Set wsinter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
                 Set dictConsumerNumber = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                 Set dictReson = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                
                  Lastrow2 = wsInter.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
             
             For Each CS In wsStart.Range("A2:CW" & lastRow1).Rows
            Snumber = CS.Cells(8).Value            
            Pnumber = CS.Cells(36).Value           
            Sgal = CS.Cells(7).Value             
            Pgal = CS.Cells(35).Value        
            
         myString = CStr(Snumber)
         myString2 = CStr(Pnumber)
            
            If Not dictConumber.Exists(myString) Then
                dictConumber.Add myString, Sgal
               
                End If
                
             If Not dictConumber.Exists(myString2) Then
               dictConumber.Add myString2, Pgal
             End If
      
         Next CS
         
         For Each G In dictConumber(myString)
       L = Application.Match(dictConumber(G), wsInter.Columns(1), 0)
        
        Next G
```

I am getting an error on line.

**For Each G In dictConumber(myString)**

I am trying to check if the dictionary values match the value on Column A in another sheet.

btw, is there a better way to do it and not use a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I managed and it is working

```
Dim dictConumber As Object
    Dim dictConsuGalactic As Object
    Dim conReason As String
    Dim CS, SCon, Snumber, Pnumber, PCon, Sgal, Pgal
    Dim G As Range
    Dim l As Range
    Dim Lastrow2 As Long
    Dim myString As String
    Dim myString2 As String
    
       
    Set dictConumber = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Lastrow2 = wsInter.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     
     For Each CS In wsStart.Range("A2:CW" & lastRow1).Rows
        Snumber = CS.Cells(8).Value
        Pnumber = CS.Cells(36).Value
        Sgal = CS.Cells(7).Value
        Pgal = CS.Cells(35).Value
        
     myString = CStr(Snumber)
     myString2 = CStr(Pnumber)
        
        If Not dictConumber.Exists(myString) Then
            dictConumber.Add myString, Sgal
           
            End If
            
         If Not dictConumber.Exists(myString2) Then
           dictConumber.Add myString2, Pgal
         End If
  
     Next CS

 Dim key As String
    Dim numberFound As Variant
    
 For Each k In dict

key = wsFinal.Cells(m, 1).Value
        numberFound = Application.Match(dictConumber(key), wsInter.Columns(1), 0)
        
        If Not IsError(numberFound) Then
            conReason = wsInter.Cells(numberFound, 8).Value
            wsFinal.Cells(m, 9).Value = conReason
        End If
    Next k
```

However, I know that I still have a lot to learn